# Recoil Async data request with atomFamily

Tags: reactjs, recoiljs

I'm using an atomFamily with a default value of a selectorFamily to get some order data:

```
export const orderState = atomFamily<Order | undefined, string>({
  key: 'orderFamily',
  default: selectorFamily({
    key: 'orderSelectorFamily',
    get:
      orderId =>
      async ({ get }) => {

        try {
          const response = await getOrder(orderId);

          return response.data;
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('error', e);
        }

      },
  }),
});
```

This is used when the page loads and `id` is captured from the URL and used in a React component:

```
export const useGetOrderValue = (orderId: string) => {
  return useRecoilValue_TRANSITION_SUPPORT_UNSTABLE(orderState(orderId));
};
```

And in the Component

```
const order = useGetOrderValue(id);
```

I also need to be able to get the order data from an order search that'll then redirect to the order page. So I'm getting the order data from a request and setting it manually using a `useRecoilCallback` function:

```
const getOrder = useRecoilCallback(
  ({ set }) =>
    async (orderId: string) => {
      try {
        const response = await requestGetOrder({ orderId });
        set(orderState(orderId), response.data);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('error', e);
      }
    },
  [],
);
```

It all seems to work fine but I feel like I'm duplicating effort within the `useRecoilCallback`. Is there a better way to do this?